# Append Folder Names in Order with Delay

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have X amount of folders in a directory, all of which need to be appended with '.r' at the end - but this must be done with ~30 seconds in between each file name edit. I.E. When I start the script I need folder1, folder2, and folder3 to go through this process: "folder1.r" *30 seconds pass* "folder2.r" *another 30 seconds* "folder3.r" etc.

I've tried cobbling together my own batch script for this, and I've gotten it *mostly* working, but it seems to not always start at the first folder (alphabetically sorted by default) - primarily, it'll start from where the script last left off, despite me having closed the command window.

**What I've got so far:**

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    ren "%%d" "%%d.r"
    timeout 3
)
```

Currently, this renames any folder in the directory to add the .r suffix. But since I've run the batch file a few times, it doesn't start off at folder1, it starts off at folder'X' where X would have been the next folder the last run of the batch would've renamed, thus the beginning folder on each run is a revolving number. If I stopped the last test batch at, say, renaming to folder20.r, then the next run of the batch starts with folder21.

---

Long story short, my current folder structure is as follows:

```
MainFolder
    Today Print001
        imageA.jpg
        imageB.jpg
        imageC.jpg
    Today Print002
        imageD.jpg
        imageE.jpg
        imageF.jpg
    Today Print003
        imageG.jpg
        imageH.jpg
        imageI.jpg
    [...]
    Today Print098
        imageR.jpg
        imageS.jpg
        imageT.jpg
    Today Print099
        imageU.jpg
        imageV.jpg
        imageW.jpg
    Today Print100
        imageX.jpg
        imageY.jpg
        imageZ.jpg
```

And my intention is to use this batch script to rename each print folder, with a 30-second pause between each name change, to become:

```
MainFolder
    Today Print001.r
        imageA.jpg
        imageB.jpg
        imageC.jpg
    Today Print002.r
        imageD.jpg
        imageE.jpg
        imageF.jpg
    Today Print003.r
        imageG.jpg
        imageH.jpg
        imageI.jpg
    [...]
    Today Print098.r
        imageR.jpg
        imageS.jpg
        imageT.jpg
    Today Print099.r
        imageU.jpg
        imageV.jpg
        imageW.jpg
    Today Print100.r
        imageX.jpg
        imageY.jpg
        imageZ.jpg
```

Of note, folder names will definitely be alphanumeric, may have spaces in them, but shouldn't have any symbols (that I can foresee.)

---

Bonus points if there's a way to have it only affect folder names that begin with, say, "bat" but this would just be icing on the cake. I haven't gotten that far into the process to research how to make that happen, and I want to be clear, I'm not asking anyone to build this entire thing for me!

Comment: Correction: my batch test file uses a timeout of 3 seconds but the finished product will be 30 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

My test from a command prompt

```
C:
cd C:\StackOverFlow\Testing
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /b /ad bat*') do (ren "%d" "%d.r"&timeout 3)
```

dir /b /ad bat*
Will get all of the folders that start with bat in the current working directory

& will allow you multiple commands on a single line

%% should be used in a batch file instead of a single %.

Comment: Got a few questions, but first I gave that string a test and it doesn't appear to work - the command window also immediately closes, and adding 'pause' to the file doesn't seem to help. Running it a few times I think I've pieced together "was unexpected at this time" somewhere in there.

Questions:
What does delims do?

Why use /f instead of /d?

Did you mean I should use single percents (%) instead of double (%%)? In my example, I was using single (as you said should be used) and in yours, you use single.

Comment: Most of your questions regarding the command can be answered by typing "for /?" at a command prompt. batch files have some nuances versus opening a command prompt and doing the same thing; I did my testing in a command prompt and never made a batch file. Your batch file should use %%. just make sure to either change to the directory (MainFolder) or specify it in the dir command

Comment: Understood, I'll look into the commands soon. As for running the script, I've got it functioning both in cmd & batch - not sure why it didn't work before as a batch (I did try %% before, must've had a typo somewhere.) But alas, I'm still at the same place as my original script - when I stop it and start again, it continues from where it left, rather than from the first folder. In my case, I had it add .r to 001 through 008 in cmd, then stopped the script. I renamed the 001-008 folders to take away the .r that the script added and tried the batch which began at 009, not 001 as I'm needing.

Comment: @RavenPanther, what file system are you using? FAT/NTFS? Anyway, adding `/on` to the `dir` command should do the trick…

Comment: @aschipfl I'm on an NTFS file system. Adding /on did the trick as far as my tests seem to find! I've found that the script won't discern between already-renamed folders though, so I'm going to have to find a way to avoid anything that's got a .r extension (I'll also have to avoid a few others) is there an easy way to do this? Lit proposed a powershell script in another answer and while I'm not opposed to it, I went with cmd/bash since I know more (though not a lot) about it than powershell.

Comment: Hm… NTFS should already sort alphabetically… Anyway, you could filter out `.r` items by this: `for /F "delims= eol=|" %d in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:N "bat*" ^| findstr /V /I "\.r$"') do (ren "%d" "%d.r" & timeout /T 3)`; or you just use another mask like `bat???.` rather than `bat*`…

Comment: @aschipfl It does technically go alphabetically, it just seems that if I interrupt the script at all (say, close out of it before it's finished) and start again, it remembers where it left off (regardless of if I remove the .r's it added) which is... interesting. Either way, gave your script a shot and it seems to do exactly what's needed! Most of the bits of it are above my head and the for /? wasn't entirely helpful as suggested by another user but I understand the gist of the core functions. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

This can be used in a `batch-file` run under `cmd`. Note that there is a check to ensure that previously existing directory names ending in ".r" are not renamed again. If you are on a supported `windows` system, `powershell` is available. When you are confident that the directories will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This will create test directories if the "goto" is removed or commented out.
GOTO NoTestDirectories
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Remove-Item -Force 'dir-*'; ^
    1..10 ^| ForEach-Object { New-Item -Type Directory -Name $('dir-{0:000}' -f $_) ^| Out-Null }
:NoTestDirectories

SET "THEDIR=%~dp0"
SET "DELAYSECONDS=5"
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    $Directories = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path '%THEDIR%'; ^
    $Directories ^| ^
        ForEach-Object { ^
            if ($_.Name -notmatch '.*\.r$') { ^
                Write-Host ""Working on directory $_.Name on PowerShell $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()""; ^
                Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name + '.r') -WhatIf; ^
                Start-Sleep -Seconds %DELAYSECONDS% ^
            } ^
        }
EXIT /B 0
```

The most recent edit will cause the directory to be the directory where this .bat file is located. See the output of `FOR /?` for details about `%~dp0`.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I'm wanting to do (I'll also need to avoid other .x/y/z extensions) but I'll need to know how to have the path simply be the script's location. I know near-zero about powershell, but I'm not against using it! What I did was place the code into a .bat file in my MainFolder, used cd'd in cmd to MainFolder then ran the .bat via cmd - I think this is what you meant by run it under cmd? After inserting the hard-coded source path into the script, it ran as expected except it started at 16, went through to 100, then 7 through 12, then 15, then 2 through 6, then 1. Unsure why!

Comment: Please try this revised code which gets all of the directories up front. Is it important that the directories are renamed in alphabetic order?

Comment: Yes, the files will usually be named like "AB1, AB2, AB3" or "3-22-22 AB1, 3-22-22 AB2" etc where they will be ran in (alpha)numerical order. For the directory, can powershell have the script run wherever .bat file is located, rather than having to specify the directory location within it? This is because the script may be moved to different folders and it needs to be user-friendly; double-clicked wherever it's located so it will only affect folders within the parent folder that contains the .bat file. In my OP, the .bat file would be within MainFolder and affect each TodayPrint folder.

Comment: So this is probably filthy in terms of how it's written - keep in mind this is the first time I've ever worked with powershell, but I feel I have a knack for catching on to scripting nomenclature. I modified your above script to only pay attention to folders that start with 'bat'. I'm still not sure how to make it force alphanumeric order of renaming, or how to run without needing the path hardcoded, but I feel it's a step in the right direction! Will post in a second comment since it's too long.

Comment: `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'Z:\BW\TEST\New' ^| ^
        ForEach-Object { ^
            if ($_.Name -notmatch '.*\.r$') { ^
    if ($_.Name -like 'bat*') { ^
                 Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name + '.r'); ^
                 Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 ^
    }^
            } ^
       }` I can't get this to format nicely, though.

Comment: The answer has been edited to make the directory where the .bat file is located. I do not yet fully understand about the "alphabetical order" issue. This script will rename directories. It will not rename files. Did you want to rename files?

Comment: I'll test the new edit soon! As for alphanumerical order, I am trying to rename directories, not files. I ran it to take screenshots and show you what I mean. So, the order of events goes: Run the script, let it modify the first 2 folders (bat reorder 001 - 002) quit the script, remove the .r that it added to said folders. Run script again, I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/1zJGzop.png) quit the script after a few seconds and remove the .r again. Run it a third time, and I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/d3W9ViT.png) where it should (preferably) begin from 001 but starts where it left off last.

Comment: New edit works as intended in regards to the director not needing to be coded in, fantastic! Thanks! My above comment still applies; while it's a minor thing and the script is certainly usable as-is, I'd like to learn how to correct it.

Comment: I am unable to produce the naming order issue as you see it on my machine. I have added code to the answer that can create test directories. This is useful in an empty directory for testing. I am running PowerShell 5.1.19041.1320 on Windows 10.